# What is this scala syntax: "users returning users.map(_._id)"

Tags: scala, slick

Can anyone explain the 2nd to last line? What is `users returning...`? Thanks.

```
val users: TableQuery[Users] = TableQuery[Users]
def create(data: Map[String, Any]): Int = {
  userId.withSession {
    implicit session =>
      val userObj = new User(
      fullname = data("fullname").toString,
      username = data("username").toString,
      password = data("password").toString)
     (users returning users.map(_._id)) += userObj // What is this doing?
     0
  }
}
```

Comment: What aspect don't you understand - the infix syntax of the `returning` method, the syntax of `+=`, the meaning of the library methods being used (in which case, what library is this code using)?

Comment: Looks like slick to me...

Comment: It's slick. I don't understand the syntax: `users returning users.map(_._id)`. I know that it is supposed to be returning the id of the inserted object, but any additional information about the grammar would be great. Or link, couldn't find anything related to `returning` in the docs. Thanks.

Comment: You could rewrite that line as `users.returning(users.map(u => u._id))`. I'm not familiar with Slick, but it looks like your add in a user to the database:

Comment: (whoops, entered too quickly) a list of user ids is used to query a collection of Users, returning a collection of users. Then `+=` adds the new user to that collection.

Comment: [Scala style guide discussion of infix notation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#arity-1)